# Match exact values in IN comparision in relationship table

Tags: sql

I have following table structure, two tables and a relationship table:

`Videos: ['id',...]`

`Categories: ['id',...]`

`Categories_Videos: ['id', 'video_id', 'category_id']`

If I want to match videos that have at least on of chosen categories I could just use IN.
For example `Select * from Categories_Videos where category_id IN [1,2];`
That way it returns all videos that have on of those categories.

How can I get videos that have both `category_id = 1` and `category_id = 2`, but videos, that only have one of those categories or none, would not be included in final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
select id,video_id,count(distinct category_id) as cnt 
from categories_videos
where category_id in (1,2)
group by id,video_id
having count(distinct category_id)=2
```

Comment: yeah, that is exactly what i've been looking for, i forgot about 'count distinct' thing in mysql. I only needed to remove grouping by id, because that messes the COUNT up. It looks like this ```select video_id, count(distinct category_id) as cnt
from category_video
where category_id in (4,5,6)
group by video_id
having cnt = 3```